# Why does my React app use so much memory?

Tags: reactjs

So, I have been experimenting with ReactJS and I have been testing its performance when loading lots of data, and I have noticed it to be quite taxing. In particular, I noticed that after my demo application loads a few thousand rows, it starts to use hundreds of megabytes. Left long enough, at about 10,000 rows, it will surpass a gigabyte of RAM used.

> Edit: I believe the high RAM usage was caused by having the React DevTools window open. It seems that using that significantly increased how much RAM is being used. However, without it open, it will still use a few hundred MB (up to 500MB, as low as 350MB) which I believe is quite a lot for just a big list.

- What is it about this app that makes it so demanding?
- Why is React updating the entire List when adding new rows (as shown by the React DevTools "Highlight Updates" feature)?
- What can I do to keep RAM usage low, without locking up the browser while everything loads?

I have provided my app below. It is entirely self-contained, so just create a file (index.html or whatever) and put all this text in it, and run the file (or optionally host it on a web server to have access to the React DevTools).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>React</title>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
ol {
    margin-left: 50px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
p { display: inline; }
img {height: 1em; }


</style>
<script type="text/babel">

class ListItem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(<li><p>{this.props.index}.</p>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" /><img src="http://www.tastyislandhawaii.com/images/spam_musubi/spam_can_open.jpg" /><a href="#">HELLO I AM SPAM NICE TO MEET YOU</a></li>);
    }
}

class List extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            TICK_INTERVAL: 500,
            ROWS_PER_TICK: 100,
            adding: false,
            list: [],
            total: 0,
            count: 0
        };

        this.start = this.start.bind(this);
        this.stop = this.stop.bind(this);
        this.addMore = this.addMore.bind(this);
    }

    start() {
        console.log("starting adding");
        this.setState({adding: true, total: 20000});
        setTimeout(this.addMore, this.state.TICK_INTERVAL);
    }

    stop() {
        console.log("stopping adding");
        this.setState({adding: false, total: 0});
    }

    addMore() {
        console.log("adding more...", this.state.adding);
        let tempCount = this.state.count;
        let tempList = [];
        for (let temp = 0; tempCount < this.state.total && temp < this.state.ROWS_PER_TICK && this.state.adding; temp++) {
            tempList.push(<ListItem key={tempCount} index={tempCount}/>);
            tempCount++;
        }
        this.setState({list: this.state.list.concat(tempList), count: tempCount});
        if (this.state.count < this.state.total) {
            if (this.state.adding) {
                setTimeout(this.addMore, this.state.TICK_INTERVAL);
            }
        } else {
            this.setState({adding: false});
        }
    }

    render() {
        let button;
        if (this.state.adding) {
            button = <button type="Submit" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.stop}>HALT!</button>
        } else {
            button = <button type="Submit" className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.start}>BOOM!</button>
        }

        return(<div>{button}<ol>{this.state.list}</ol></div>);
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<List/>, document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
</head>
<body><div id="root"></div></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tested on Chrome 59: 20k rows - total memory used 120Mb, memory was being allocated evenly throughout the execution.

Comment: Hi, thanks for giving it a try. Did the image load for you? It was giving me a 503 error, so for accurate testing I've updated the url with a new image. Besides, even without the image loading, all 20,000 rows took over 500MB (as viewed from the Chrome task manager, also version 59). It also did allocate the memory evenly. Why is it different between your browser and I?

Comment: I noticed that ReactDevTool affects it significantly. I had no ReactDevTool installed, now memory profiler shows more than 2x consumption. Try to disable it and test again.

Comment: @AlexM yes, that definitely increased the memory consumption significantly. I'm unable to get the 120MB you got, but I am certainly getting less than before (still hovering at the 400MB mark). Is this a normal amount of RAM usage for an app like this?

Comment: I don't know why the difference is so huge. Maybe you have some other extensions installed that affect the memory consumption. Try to test it on a different machine.

Comment: "Why is React updating the entire List when adding new rows" - it doesn't. React DevTools shows it adds new rows, but does not updates previous.

Comment: @AlexM Why is the React DevTools extension showing the entire List with a blue outline (when the Highlight Updates feature is enabled)? I thought that meant the component is being updated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was in the React DevTools extension. While it was active, it would cause the RAM usage of the app to skyrocket. When I loaded up my app after killing the process (and I didn't open React DevTools) my app used a normal amount of RAM.

Comment: what is "normal amount of RAM" ? we build an app which display thousands of data displayed as list with material-ui and used react-virtualize to try to optimise the app, we use almost 150Mo of RAM, is it "normal" ?

Comment: I suppose by "normal" I am implying an "expected" amount of RAM.

Comment: I was taken back when my React application (that has a socket that updates states many times per second) would take 2 gigs of RAM in the Chrome task manager. Closing the Chrome dev tools itself fixed it, even if you don't have to uninstall the React DevTools

Comment: You've saved my project. I can't believe this was the issue.

Comment: @PatrickFerreira is right. What is "normal"? Guys, 1 MB =  1 MILLION bytes. Display thousands of data that uses 150 MB RAM, it is 150 KB per ROW!!!! 150.000 bytes per row!!!! WT..//F?!?! It is a lot of memory.

Comment: For me "Normal" for a web page in CHrome uses 150 to 600MB, when it goes over a GB but u have text of 10-15 MB (maximum) on a rich text editor, with just a 50-60  lines being headings or any thing else than plain normal text with any custom styling then its a worry @patrick-ferreira (no big images besides a 200Kb logo

Comment: Just regular text (1 or 2 words per row). however, we use material-ui... now I know it uses *a lot* of styling and DOM elements underneath... it can explains the amount of RAM used tho.